# long comments management

Tags: align, environments

I am looking to keep the comments on the side so I don't want an intertext or short intertext but make the long line two lines and keep everything equally spaced! What is the trick/ command?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor,geometry}
\begin{document}
$\begin{aligned}[t] \dfrac{20-5x^{2}}{x^{2}+x-6}&=\dfrac{5(4-x^{2})}{(x+3) 
(x-2)} && \textcolor{blue}{\text{Factor}} \\
                                                   &=\dfrac{5(2+x)(2-x)} 
{(x+3)(x-2)} && \textcolor{blue}{\text{Factor completely}} \\

&=\dfrac{5(2+x) \cdot \textcolor{red}{-1}(\colorbox{cyan!25!white}{$x-2$})} 
{(x+3)(\colorbox{cyan!25!white}{$x-2$})} && \textcolor{blue}{\text{Notice 
opposites in $2-x$ and $x-2$. Write $2-x$ as $-1(x-2)$ and simplify}} \\

&=-\dfrac{5(2+x)}{x+3}
\end{aligned}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something that I do in such cases.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor,geometry}

\newbox\aebox
\newcommand\aecomment[1]{%%
  \begin{lrbox}\aebox
    \begin{minipage}[t]{2in}
      \raggedright
      \textcolor{blue}{#1}%%
    \end{minipage}%%
  \end{lrbox}%%
  \raisebox{0pt}[\height][0pt]{\usebox{\aebox}}}
\begin{document}

$
  \begin{aligned}[t] 
    \dfrac{20-5x^{2}}{x^{2}+x-6} &=\dfrac{5(4-x^{2})}{(x+3) (x-2)} && \textcolor{blue}{\text{Factor}}            \\
                                 &=\dfrac{5(2+x)(2-x)}{(x+3)(x-2)} && \textcolor{blue}{\text{Factor completely}} \\
                                 &=\dfrac{5(2+x) \cdot \textcolor{red}{-1}(\colorbox{cyan!25!white}{$x-2$})} 
                                         {(x+3)(\colorbox{cyan!25!white}{$x-2$})} 
                                 %% && \textcolor{blue}{\text{Notice opposites in $2-x$ and $x-2$. Write $2-x$ as $-1(x-2)$ and simplify}} \\
                                 && \aecomment{Notice opposites in $2-x$ and $x-2$. Write $2-x$ as $-1(x-2)$ and simplify} \\
                                 &=-\dfrac{5(2+x)}{x+3}
  \end{aligned}
$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now, I should caution that I've nulled out the depth of the comment.  That means if you write something like:

```
$
  \begin{aligned}[t] 
    \dfrac{20-5x^{2}}{x^{2}+x-6} &=\dfrac{5(4-x^{2})}{(x+3) (x-2)} && \textcolor{blue}{\text{Factor}}            \\
                                 &=\dfrac{5(2+x)(2-x)}{(x+3)(x-2)} && \textcolor{blue}{\text{Factor completely}} \\
                                 &=\dfrac{5(2+x) \cdot \textcolor{red}{-1}(\colorbox{cyan!25!white}{$x-2$})} 
                                         {(x+3)(\colorbox{cyan!25!white}{$x-2$})} 
                                 %% && \textcolor{blue}{\text{Notice opposites in $2-x$ and $x-2$. Write $2-x$ as $-1(x-2)$ and simplify}} \\
                                 && \aecomment{Notice opposites in $2-x$ and $x-2$. Write $2-x$ as $-1(x-2)$ and simplify} \\
                                 &=-\dfrac{5(2+x)}{x+3}
                                 && \textcolor{red}{\text{\bfseries Smashes into line above!!!}}
  \end{aligned}
$
```

You'll get a clash between the comments.  So, be advised.

[image]

I tend to use such comments sparingly.  So such clashes are not a significant issue for me.  But here you can see what happens if I don't null out the depth:

[image]

If you don't mind the extra space created in the equation by the long comment, then just remove the `\raisebox` portion of the details.

This crashing can be *avoided* by using `\raisebox` to actually *raise* the box by a specified amount.  Here I redefine the `\aecomment`

```
\newbox\aebox
\newcommand\aecomment[2][0pt]{%%
  \begin{lrbox}\aebox
    \begin{minipage}[t]{2in}
      \raggedright
      \textcolor{blue}{#2}%%
    \end{minipage}%%
  \end{lrbox}%%
  \raisebox{#1}[\height][0pt]{\usebox{\aebox}}}
```

Calling it as follows:

```
$
  \begin{aligned}[t] 
    \dfrac{20-5x^{2}}{x^{2}+x-6} &=\dfrac{5(4-x^{2})}{(x+3) (x-2)} && \textcolor{blue}{\text{Factor}}            \\
                                 &=\dfrac{5(2+x)(2-x)}{(x+3)(x-2)} && \textcolor{blue}{\text{Factor completely}} \\
                                 &=\dfrac{5(2+x) \cdot \textcolor{red}{-1}(\colorbox{cyan!25!white}{$x-2$})} 
                                         {(x+3)(\colorbox{cyan!25!white}{$x-2$})} 
                                 && \aecomment[2.5ex]{Notice opposites in $2-x$ and $x-2$. Write $2-x$ as $-1(x-2)$ and simplify} \\
                                 &=-\dfrac{5(2+x)}{x+3}
                                 && \textcolor{red}{\text{\bfseries No crashing into line above!!!}}
  \end{aligned}
$
```

Resulting in no clash but also not effecting the spacing in the equation itself either.

[image]

Comment: It is close but yes it smashes into the next comment area. If we could move notice somewhat. I see the next solution

Comment: Can the raisebox help move the line starting with Notice up towards the top of the numerator fraction?

Comment: @MathScholar I've just updated the answer to reflect exactly that issue.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution with the `stackengine` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor,geometry}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\begin{document}

$\begin{aligned}[t] \dfrac{20-5x^{2}}{x^{2}+x-6}&=\dfrac{5(4-x^{2})}{(x+3)
(x-2)} && \textcolor{blue}{\text{Factor}} \\
                                                   &=\dfrac{5(2+x)(2-x)}
{(x+3)(x-2)} && \textcolor{blue}{\text{Factor completely}} \\
&=\dfrac{5(2+x) \cdot \textcolor{red}{-1}(\colorbox{cyan!25!white}{$x-2$})}
{(x+3)(\colorbox{cyan!25!white}{$x-2$})} && \textcolor{blue}{\Centerstack[l]{Notice
opposites in $2-x$ and $x-2$. \\Write $2-x$ as $-1(x-2)$ and simplify}} \\
&=-\dfrac{5(2+x)}{x+3}
\end{aligned}$

\end{document}
```

[image]